# Passing string in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I have this coffeescript function for dynamic select boxes, and I need to pass "modelsSelect" content to this other script, but I just can't get it working.

**diys.coffee**

```
dynamicSelect = (makesSelect, modelsSelect) ->
  $(document).on 'change', makesSelect, (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_make_models',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        make_id: $("#{makesSelect} option:selected").val(),
        'models': modelsSelect
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic make select OK!")


dynamicSelect '#diy_attached_vehicles_attributes_0_make', '#diy_attached_vehicles_attributes_0_model'
dynamicSelect '#diy_attached_vehicles_attributes_1_make', '#diy_attached_vehicles_attributes_1_model'
```

**update_make_models.coffee**

```
$(models).empty()
    .append("<%= escape_javascript(render "make_models/make_model") %>")
```

**make_models/_make_models.html.erb**

```
<% @models.collect do |models| %>
   <option value="<%= models.id %>"><%= models.make_model_name %></option>
<% end %>
```

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
**Edit**

Heres part of my form containig those select boxes

```
<div class="vehicle_field">
    <%= f.fields_for :attached_vehicles do |av| %>
       <p>Select make</p>
       <%= av.select :make, options_for_select(@makes.collect { |make|[make.make_name, make.id] }, 0), {} %><br>
       <p>Select model</p>
       <%= av.select :model, (render "make_models/make_model"), {} %><br>
       ...
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "but I just can't get it working?" What exactly does happen or what does not?

Comment: When I select make in makes select box, it should send make_id of selected make(as it does), and send "modelsSelect" content(id of models select box) to "update_make_models.coffee" so it empties and appends it. But now when I select make, nothing happens to models select box, and in browsers console i get "AJAX Error: parsererror".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

**diys.coffee**

```
dynamicSelect = (makesSelect, modelsSelect) ->
  $(document).on 'change', makesSelect, (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_make_models',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        make_id: $("#{makesSelect} option:selected").val(),
        model_div_id: modelsSelect
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic make select OK!")


dynamicSelect '#diy_attached_vehicles_attributes_0_make', '#diy_attached_vehicles_attributes_0_model'
dynamicSelect '#diy_attached_vehicles_attributes_1_make', '#diy_attached_vehicles_attributes_1_model'
```

**diys_controller.rb**

```
def update_make_models
  @models = MakeModel.where("make_id = ?", params[:make_id])
  @modelsid = params[:model_div_id]
  respond_to do |format|
     format.js
  end
end
```

**update_make_models.coffee**

```
$("<%= @modelsid %>").empty()
    .append("<%= escape_javascript(render "make_models/make_model") %>")
```